# How do I combine MySQL statements with an "IF"?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I combine these into one statement using MySQL?

```
SELECT COUNT(barcode) AS count
FROM movieitemdetails_custom
WHERE username = 'John';

if count is == 0

    SELECT title FROM movieitemdetails WHERE barcode = '12345';

else

    SELECT title FROM movieitemdetails_custom WHERE username = 'John';

end-if
```

Comment: Use left joins and nvl

Comment: `NVL()` doesn't exist in MySQL.

Comment: I have also some hint for someone who votes down. Please first try to understand question, then vote. You are not the sage. Please try to not be a poor man. Someone has a trouble and he asks sages for advice.

Comment: Thank you @Max I wanted to say something but didn't want to make people even more angry. Apparently a down vote is easier than just helping someone.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to get the list:

```
SELECT title
FROM movieitemdetails
WHERE barcode = '12345'
AND (
  SELECT COUNT(barcodes)
  FROM movieitemdetails_custom
  WHERE username = 'John'
) = 0
UNION SELECT title
FROM movieitemdetails_custom
WHERE username = 'John'
AND (
  SELECT COUNT(barcodes)
  FROM movieitemdetails_custom
  WHERE username = 'John'
) > 0
```

It's the end of a looong day so I hope I got the count zero/nonzero logic straight :)

BTW, I agree with @Max that the downvote was undeserved. I voted the question up.

Comment: Any solution for this? `The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`

Comment: Not with plain SQL I'm afraid. If they have a different number of columns then you just can't do it with plain SQL. You could maybe make the unmatched columns null, but that starts to look like a hack.

Comment: So would a stored procedure be better suited for this type of query then?

Comment: Probably. If I were forced to do something simiilar in Oracle or SQL Server I'd try a stored procedure here, but I don't know MySQL stored procedures that well. If you have a front end that's calling the database you could call once for the count and the second time with one of the two queries. You'd lose a bit of time with the overhead of calling twice, but that would at least keep the queries simple, plus you'd avoid the double count my answer uses. It may be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN countt = 0 THEN (SELECT barcodes FROM movieitemdetails WHERE username = 'John') 
 ELSE (SELECT barcodes FROM movieitemdetails_custom WHERE username = 'John')
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(`mdc`.`title`, `md`.`title`, 'NO TITLE') `title`
FROM (SELECT NULL) der
    LEFT JOIN `movieitemdetails_custom` `mdc` ON `mdc`.`username` = 'John'
    LEFT JOIN `movieitemdetails` `md` ON `md`.`barcodes` = '1234567890';
```